# UIImageView, Image doesn't load when project is rebuilt

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimageview, uiimage

So I'm saving my image in my local directory like this..

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
                UIImage * imageToSave = self.imgViewUser.image;
                NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

                [binaryImageData writeToFile:
                 [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",self.txtUserName.text ]] atomically:YES] ;

                NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",basePath,self.txtUserName.text];

[user setValue:final forKey:@"imagePath"];
```

Im using CoreData to save it. Then in retrieving it to other controllers, Im doing this..

```
NSString *imagePath = [self.user valueForKey:@"imagePath"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
self.imgViewUser.image = image;
```

At first after adding my image and search for the user, I can see the image, but when I re run the project, the image doesn't load. help! :)

Comment: Do you delete previous build/ change the simulator OS version when you re-run the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue in one of my projects in the past.

Don't save your full image path.

You need to store only image and every time when you run the project you just need to append your "username.png" to your path. This will work for every time.